# pytest-selenium installed but not available as plugin for pytest. What have I done wrong?

Tags: selenium, pytest, pytest-selenium

I've installed pytest-selenium, but I cannot use it with pytest.

```
  def test_sanity(selenium):
E       fixture 'selenium' not found
>       available fixtures: cache, capfd, capfdbinary, caplog, capsys, capsysbinary, check, cov, dash_br, dash_duo, dash_process_server, dash_thread_server, dashr, dashr_server, doctest_namespace, install_cbm_dash, install_dir, metadata, mock, mocker, monkeypatch, most_recent_installer_exe, no_cover, pytestconfig, record_property, record_testsuite_property, record_xml_attribute, recwarn, run_installer, tmp_path, tmp_path_factory, tmpdir, tmpdir_factory, uninstall_after_run
>       use 'pytest --fixtures [testpath]' for help on them.

λ pytest --fixtures
======================================================= test session starts ======================================================= platform win32 -- Python 3.6.8, pytest-4.6.3, py-1.8.0, pluggy-0.12.0
rootdir: C:\Users\dbak\Downloads\cmder
plugins: allure-pytest-2.7.0, dash-1.7.0, flaky-3.6.0, check-0.3.5, cov-2.10.0, html-1.21.1, metadata-1.8.0, mock-1.10.4, profiling-1.7.0
```

What might be the root cause of this? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

This means that there is no fixture called `selenium`.

You probably need to initialise selenium. You can do this inside every function you want to use it, but that is quite annoying. Therefore the better alternative is adding a function in `conftest.py`. That way you can keep using `selenium` as an arg for your test functions.

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture()
def selenium():
    #do some initialisation for selenium here.
    return your_selenium_instance
```